# Is it possible to guarantee an array to be sorted in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typing

I wonder if it's possible to create a type that guarantees a sort order for an array in Typescript.

I feel that Flowtype might be able to do something like this through the 'Opaque' type, but I'm not sure if there's a good Typescript equivalent.

This is generally what I'm looking for:

```
function foo(input: SortedArray<string>) {

  // Only accepts arrays that are sorted

}

const data = ['d', 'b', 'a'];
foo(data); // fails
sort(data);
foo(data); // doesn't fail
data.push('c');
foo(data); // fails again
```

I'm not looking for this exact snippet to work, and I also don't expect Typescript to 'know' if the array was sorted at run-time. All I would like to do is for typescript to guarantee:

- sort() was called on this array.
- the array was not mutated after sorting.

Substitute `sort` for any other function, but you get the idea.

I think a very similar feature to 'marking an array as sorted' could be 'marking a string to be a valid url'.

I don't necessarily want to introduce new base types or extend them, I just want some guarantees that a value has passed some pre-condition. I might be using incorrect terminology here but I feel that this is possible in typed lambda calculus, haskell and somewhat through flow via the Opaque type.

Comment: you can use the Priority Queue found in this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-collections

Comment: You could always go for the old-fashioned approach of having a class whose constructor sorts the array upon instantiation. But in terms of having a type which itself enforces the precondition, I don't believe Typescript is quite powerful enough to do this.

Comment: You mean to enforce through the type system that a given value *must* be a sorted array? No, I don't think that's possible.

Comment: What do you want to see, exactly?  You can make a `SortedArray` class that behaves however you want at runtime, and add only those methods that maintain the invariant.  Are you just looking for [nominal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) types?  I think it would help if you write some code that explains your use case: what do you want to see compile with no error, and what do you want to see produce a compiler error?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback, I think @SilvioMayolo is right and there is simply no way. I will add an example of what I'm looking for. Someone can answer this with 'this is not possible' and maybe a new answer can be added a couple of years from now ;)

Comment: @jcalz added some more detail

Comment: The type system would have issues describing sort order. e.g. SortedArray<Person>, what exactly would that be sorted on? Name?

Comment: You can't have `sort(data)` narrow the type of `data` from `Array<string>` to `SortedArray<string>`... but you *can* have `sort(data)` *return* a `SortedArray<string>`.  Would that work for you?  Mutation of values makes types like this difficult... again, you wouldn't have `data.push()` widen the type of `data` from `SortedArray<string>` back to `Array<string>`, but you could have `data.pushNew()` *return* an `Array<string>`.

Comment: @RogerJohansson You're right, that's probably due to my poor naming. My real-world scenario actually sorts a list of objects based on a specific key. So think of `SortedArray` as a user-defined type in this hypothetical type system