# How to require a type be a sorted Array, not just an Array

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in typescript to require a type be a *sorted* array?

In Haskell, something like [sorted-array](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/sorted-list).

Comment: [Is it possible to guarantee an array to be sorted in Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54891752/is-it-possible-to-guarantee-an-array-to-be-sorted-in-typescript)

Comment: Why the downvote? It's not an unreasonable question, particularly since unfortunately the TypeScript documentation is still spotty and awkward to navigate (although they're trying to fix that). A quick [search](/search?q=%5Btypescript%5D+type+for+sorted+array) doesn't find anything (although @Joe did above -- nice one! -- though sadly it doesn't have an actual posted answer).

Comment: Thanks. I also found that post and tried to search the docs. I guess it appears to be currently not possible. Bummer. I could really use such functionality.